# JavaFX not repainting when binding canvas size to parent

Tags: canvas, javafx, repaint

The code below triggers doDrawing() when the window resizes but the existing graphics aren't invalidated/repainted (see link to image). My understanding is that JavaFX handles this under the hood. What am I missing? Thanks.

EDIT: I found that if I call clearRect on the GraphicsContext, specifying the whole canvas, it will repaint correctly but again, I think JavaFX identifies what needs repainting.

[Image of canvas not repainting correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ud70.png)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Class1 extends Application {
    Canvas canvas;

    public Class1() { }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        canvas = new Canvas(300,300);
        border.setCenter(canvas);

        Scene scene = new Scene(border);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        canvas.widthProperty().bind(border.widthProperty());
        canvas.heightProperty().bind(border.heightProperty());

        scene.heightProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number>
                    observableValue, Number number, Number number2) -> {
            doDrawing();
        });

        scene.widthProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number>
                    observableValue, Number number, Number number2) -> {
            doDrawing();
        });

        doDrawing();
    }

    public void doDrawing()
    {
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gc.strokeRect(10, 10, canvas.getWidth() - 10, canvas.getHeight() - 10);
    }
}
```

JDK1.8.0_121
Netbeans 8.0.2
Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a misunderstanding on your side here. JavaFX does not automatically repaint anything in a canvas. I you change its size you have to draw everyting again as you did in your last update.

Comment: I think I'm confusing the fact that JavaFX handles double buffering automatically with the need to manually invalidate sections of the screen that need to be repainted. Somehow I thought JavaFX was looking at the new drawing, comparing it to the old drawing and updating only what has changed.

Comment: Are there any methods besides GraphicsContext.clearRect() that can be used to do this? This is all I'm finding.

Comment: No, for the canvas that's all.